# "Maps" feature in Journey builder?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, feature-activation

I didn't find any information about a feature that seemed to exist in elder versions of Journey Builder and we want to know if it is possible to activate it or you know any similar solution for planning campaigns and grouping actions.

I put two example images :)

[image]
[image]

Thank you very, very much!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Journey Maps was announced at the Connections 2014 conference but never made it to GA. It has since been withdrawn from the product roadmap and will be replaced with Campaign Maps. Salesforce has not disclosed details of this upcoming feature or provided a timeframe of its availability.